# Adipoli jQuery Image Hover Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am using [Adipoli jQuery Image Hover Effects](http://jobyj.in/adipoli/) but I am having problems changing some properties. Image changes to grayscale and onmouseover it changes to color, but then I have set that when I click image it should stay colored, but it's broken, because instead of replacing image it adds image on top and over it another image (but it's undefined so it's not shown). Below is the code which I am using, but you can download full example from [www.filedropper.com/adipoli-test](http://www.filedropper.com/adipoli-test)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#image1').adipoli({
        'startEffect' : 'grayscale',
        'hoverEffect' : 'popout'
    });
}); 

function select(n){       
    $('#image1').adipoli({
        'startEffect' : 'normal',
        'hoverEffect' : 'popout'
    });                        
}
</script>
<div style="width:650px; height: 400px; display:block; margin: 60px;">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="select(1)"><img src="image1.jpg" class="img1" id="image1"></a>
</div>
```

I would really like to make this happen and I hope that some jQuery expert can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I make new jquery function "adipoliDestroy", which destroy adipoli from element. Now before reinit adipoli on element, call destroy and init adipoli again.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.adipoliDestroy = function(){
        var clone = this.clone().css('display', 'block'),
                wrapper = null;
        if (wrapper = this.parents('.adipoli-wrapper')){
            wrapper.replaceWith(clone);
        }
        return clone;
    }
})(jQuery);

function select(n){
    $('#image1').adipoliDestroy().adipoli({
        'startEffect' : 'normal',
        'hoverEffect' : 'popout'
    });
}
```